# Squid access logging only specific ACLs?

Tags: logging, squid, access-control-list

In squid, is it possible to enable access logging only on a specific ACL?

If so, how?

We have done quite a few searches and were unable to find the proper conf syntax :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
acl log_this src x.x.x.x. y.y.y.y.y z.z.z.z.z
access_log /var/log/squid common log_this
```

Answer (score 0):

big trouble in little squid 3.4?

default points to accesses logging

```
access_log /var/log/squid/access.log
```

Below acls without log

```
access_log none my_acl
```

Does not work, all is logged on access.log
I already try changing the order of this two lines (low to up and up to low) but does not work.

Have you any idea?

Comment: A way that I done was: access_log /var/log/squid/access.log !myacl